# Installing Safari 4 on OS X 10.6.4

Tags: mac-osx, safari

Really need the ability (for backwards compatibility's sake ) to run Safar 4 on OS 10.6.4 instead of Safari 5. Would be sick to have both running at the same time. :D

SOLVED: Found this website finally. :P
http://michelf.com/projects/multi-safari/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [this](http://support.apple.com/kb/dl877) download. Not sure if downgrading works, though.